# how to organize read\write to lsb in ruby

Tags: ruby, steganography

I need to hide message in picture, for example

```
pixels = []
File.open("file.jpg","rb").each_line{|line| pixels.push line}
```

in first element of pixels array we have string => "\a\a\b\a\x06\n"

to show lsb we can use

> pixels[0].unpack('b*')

=> ["111000001110000000010000111000000110000001010000"]

if we want to see what is it in ascii we use

> pixels[0].unpack('C*')

=> [7, 7, 8, 7, 6, 10]

What should i do to organize read\write secret message mechanism in least significant bit?

Comment: How to 'organize'? I don't understand your question. Are you asking _how_ to write to the least significant bit?

Comment: yes, English is not my native. I had asked about reading and writing to the lsb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had founded an answer to this question and I had written an article here http://blog.rubyruby.ru/blog/2014/03/14/bitmap_images_and_lsb_hiding/ with examples